# How to insert into std::map?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a std iterator I could use to insert elements into std::map using a std algorithm (for example std::copy) ?

I need a container to link one object to a string, and I thought about using std::map. Is there a better container? Forgot to say - items needs to be sorted.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think what the OP is looking for is `std::inserter(mymap, mymap.end())`

so you can do:

```
std::copy( inp.begin(), inp.end(), std::inserter(mymap, mymap.end()) );
```

The input types must be a pair type that your map takes, otherwise your algorithm would need to be `std::transform` with a function/functor to convert the input type into such a `std::pair`.

inserter is not actually an iterator but a templated function that produces an iterator (`std::insert_iterator`, which is a templated type but the type is automatically resolved in the function call).

Comment: If the input range is sorted, using `.begin()` for the second parameter should make things faster. Otherwise it doesn't really matter. See for example http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/insert_iterator.html .

Answer (score 14):

In order to insert into `std::map` you need to use `std::make_pair()`.

For example:

```
std::map<int,std::string> Map;
Map.insert(std::make_pair(5,"Hello"));
```

Try something similar. :)

Comment: This is not what he's after. He's not asking how to insert an item into a map. He's looking for a way of inserting elements into a map using one of the STL algorithms.

Comment: Around the time this question was asked and answered I was a bit obsessed about reputation points here, and actually suspected something about Prasoon who managed to get 13 upvotes for answers like this one.

Comment: Not an answer to the question: "Is there a std iterator I could use...?"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `std::copy` can insert several elements into a map, if you use a `std::insert_iterator` as the OutputIterator (use the helper function `std::inserter` to create these; this way, the template type can be inferred). The "elements" of a std::map are key-value pairs, which you can create with `std::make_pair`, as Prasoon illustrates. (The actual type is `std::pair<Key, Value>`; again, the helper function allows for template type deduction.) If you have the keys in one sequence and the values in another, you should be able to use `std::transform` to produce a sequence of key-value pairs.