# Using std::transform to convert a std::vector<struct{key; val;}> into a std::map<key, val>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

Given these types:

```
struct ComplexLibraryThing { /*lots of fields*/};
typedef std::map<int, ComplexLibraryThing> MyMap;
struct ShadowComplexLibraryThing { /*Shadow of ComplexLibraryThing*/};
struct MyVecType { int a; ShadowComplexLibraryThing b; };
typedef std::vector<MyVecType> MyVector;
```

I can do this for serialisation (my serialisation library doesn't support map-like types):

```
MyVecType map2pair(std::pair<int, ComplexLibraryThing> const &myPair)
{
    MyVecType retVal;
    retVal.a = myPair.first;
    retVal.b = convertForSerialisation(myPair.second);
    return retVal;
}

MyMap myMap = {...};
MyVector myVector;
std::transform(myMap.begin(),
               myMap.end(),
               std::back_inserter(myVector),
               map2pair);
```

I then send the vector over to the receiver which wants to reconstruct the `MyMap`. However, I cannot find a suitable `<algorithm>` template that does de-serialisation like this:

```
MyMap myNewMap;
for (auto const &entry: myVector)
    myNewMap[entry.a] = convertForDeserialisation(entry.b);
```

How would I write this using an `<algorithm>`?

(Note that the `ComplexLibraryThing` type within the map cannot be easily altered, but I also have a `ShadowComplexLibraryThing` which can be)

Comment: Can you modify `MyVecType` at all? As in, adding member functions?

Comment: Why don't you do the same on the other end: `std::transform` with a function? Or combine `std::for_each()` with a lambda? I guess I'm missing something :-/

Comment: @piwi I'm not sure what to replace `std::back_inserter` with...

Comment: Your modification doesn't answer my question. Can you modify `MyVecType` itself?

Comment: @StoryTeller Oops, I mis-read your comment. I have to use a `std::vector` (or `boost::array`) type.

Comment: If you construct a `std::pair` with the key and the value as its fields, it can be inserted in the map. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: You could use [`std::inserter()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter)

Comment: I'm becoming frustrated, really. I ask if you can change in any way `struct MyVecType {  a, b };`

Comment: @StoryTeller I can change it to some degree.

Comment: @ZalmanStern Please go on, with an answer if necessary.

Comment: So, I'm not answering the question, but as an aside... Google's [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#maps) serialization / deserialization tooling supports `map`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375180/how-to-insert-into-stdmap and invert the conversion from `std::pair` to MyVecType.

Comment: @druckermanly FYI, I'm using [ROS Messaging](http://wiki.ros.org/msg), so  that is out of the question.

Comment: Incidentally, any reason you want to use an algorithm?  The range-based for-loop strikes me as a lot simpler than the transform.  (Particularly if you change the body to `myNewMap.insert(std::make_pair(entry.a, convertForDeserialisation(entry.b));` (which avoids default constructing the map entry and then assigning to it.).

Comment: @MartinBonner Good question! As I was writing the question I realised the range-based for was much, much simpler, and probably easier for my colleagues to understand, or indeed for me to understand next month.

Comment: On avoiding default initialization: map2pair should be  `return {myPair.first, convertForSerialisation(myPair.second)};`  - will even work if the second type is only movable (not copyable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the key "trick" missing is `std::inserter`. Here's a little demo.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct foo {int a; int b;};

std::vector<foo> GenerateSource() {
  return {};
} 

std::pair<int, int> ConvertFooToMapPair(const foo& f) {
    return {f.a, f.b};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::map<int, int> destination;
  std::vector<foo> source = GenerateSource();
  std::transform(
    source.begin(), source.end(),
    std::inserter(destination, destination.end()),
    ConvertFooToMapPair);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This post shows how to create an inserter for std::map:

[How to insert into std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375180/how-to-insert-into-stdma)‌​p

The type of the thing iterated over needs to be a `std::pair<KeyType, EntryType>` (the so called `value_type` of `std::map`).

I think this looks like so:

```
std::pair<int, ComplexLibraryThing> vec2pair(const MyVecType &myVec)
{
    return std::make_pair(myVec.a,
                          transformForDeserialization(myVec.b));
}

MyVector myVector = {...};
MyMap myMap;
std::transform(myVector.begin(),
               myVector.end(),
               std::inserter(myMap, myMap.end()),
               vec2pair);
```

Comment: I think the `make_pair` needs to be `std::make_pair(myVec.a, transformForDeserialization(myVec.b))`

Comment: Beat me by two minutes, but my thoughts exactly!